# Problems with USB-Devices using VDR

Tags: backup-restoration, snapshot, vmware-vdr

I'm using VDR on vSphere4. It works sucessfully. I've already backuped several VMs with VDR and I like it very much. But now we got a problem. We have 2 VMs, using an USB-Device Server with a stick plugged in, which is definetely need by these 2 VMs for Licensing and so. Every time, I start the Backup process, the VMs lost the communication to the USB-Server and its stick after building the snapshot and while online. Because of that, the software on these VMs can't work correctly. I have to restart both Machines to solve this problem. These fact is bad for an automatic backup. Does VDR have a special function for those cases or is something like this already known?

It would be no problem, to shutdown the servers for building snapshots on Saturday or Sunday. Can VDR initiate a shutdown before starting the backup process? Otherwise I must try to use scripts, but that wouldn't be so nice.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, and not one I've come across before - if it does it at the point of snap the VCB's not going to help you either.

I know you can get USB-servers that but know little of them myself, perhaps that might be a way around the problem. Search SF for usb server and see if you find anything that sounds promising.